# Is it possible to loop through 2 levels in an array on Deluege?

Tags: arrays, json, zoho, zoho-deluge

I need to get the address lines from the following JSON Data in Deluge. AdressLine1 2 and 3 are nested below Address and Current Tenants. I'm not sure how to list the subsequent levels

```
{
"Id": 0,
"PropertyId": 0,
"UnitId": 0,
"UnitNumber": "string",
"LeaseFromDate": "2019-08-24",
"LeaseToDate": "2019-08-24",
"LeaseType": "None",
"LeaseStatus": "Active",
"IsEvictionPending": true,
"TermType": "MonthToMonth",
"RenewalOfferStatus": "NotSet",
"CurrentTenants": [
{
"Id": 0,
"FirstName": "string",
"LastName": "string",
"Email": "string",
"AlternateEmail": "string",
"PhoneNumbers": [
{
"Number": "string",
"Type": "NotSet"
}
],
"CreatedDateTime": "2019-08-24T14:15:22Z",
"EmergencyContact": {
"Name": "string",
"RelationshipDescription": "string",
"Phone": "string",
"Email": "string"
},
"DateOfBirth": "2019-08-24",
"SMSOptInStatus": "NotSet",
"Address": {
"AddressLine1": "string",
"AddressLine2": "string",
"AddressLine3": "string",
"City": "string",
"State": "string",
"PostalCode": "string",
"Country": "UnitedStates"
},
```

I can get the first level but I'm confused how to get the other levels listed.

```
for each  row in rows
    {
        info row;
        UnitNumber = row.getJSON("UnitNumber");
        info "UnitNumber is: " + UnitNumber;
        LeaseStartDate = row.getJSON("LeaseFromDate");
        info "Lease Start Date is: " + LeaseStartDate;
        UnitId = row.getJSON("UnitId");
        info "UnitID is: " + UnitId;
        CurrentTenants = row.getJSON("CurrentTenants").toJSONList();
        for each  Address in CurrentTenants
        {
            Address = CurrentTenants.getJSON("Address");
        }
        info "Address: " + Address;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it almost right.

You just need to loop each of children object keys in `Address`.

Such as,

```
for each  row in rows
    {
        info row;
        UnitNumber = row.getJSON("UnitNumber");
        info "UnitNumber is: " + UnitNumber;
        LeaseStartDate = row.getJSON("LeaseFromDate");
        info "Lease Start Date is: " + LeaseStartDate;
        UnitId = row.getJSON("UnitId");
        info "UnitID is: " + UnitId;
        CurrentTenants = row.getJSON("CurrentTenants").toJSONList();
        for each  CurrentTenant in CurrentTenants
        {
            tenantAddressObj = CurrentTenant.getJSON("Address");
            tenantAddress = "";
            addressObjKey = tenantAddressObj.keys();
            for each objKey in addressObjKey {
                 tenantAddress = tenantAddress + tenantAddressObj.get(objKey) + ", ";
            }
            // TODO cleanup of trailing comma
            info "Address: " + tenantAddress;
        }
    }
```